# ASP.Net Uploader - improve compression and downsizing

Tags: asp.net, compression, uploader, downsize

I use Classic ASP, not ASP.Net but I do have an ASP.net uploader that does a pretty good job.  With some large files it compresses the image and makes it a good workable size.  But there are times where the image actual is larger than the original.

I would really appreciate it if one of your experts can tweak my code and make it more efficient.  Not knowing Net, I am at a loss.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim strFileName As String = String.Format("Photo{0}.jpg", hdnAgentID.value)
        If fupPhoto.HasFile Then
            Try
                If fupPhoto.PostedFile.ContentLength <= 10000000 Then
                    fupPhoto.SaveAs("M:\my path\" & strFileName)
                    resizeImage("M:\my path & strFileName)
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                lblAlert.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.ToString()
            End Try
            hdnPhotoURL.Value = String.Format(https://websiteaddress/uploads/{0}, strFileName)
        End If
        
        strFileName = String.Format("Logo{0}.jpg", hdnAgentID.Value)
        If fupLogo.HasFile Then
            Try
                If fupLogo.PostedFile.ContentLength <= 10000000 Then
                    fupLogo.SaveAs("M:\my path\" & strFileName)
                   resizeImage("M:\my path\" & strFileName)
                End If
    
            Catch ex As Exception
                lblAlert.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.ToString()
            End Try
            hdnLogoURL.Value = String.Format(https://websiteaddress/uploads/{0}, strFileName)
        End If

        
        'Update UI and Create JS to populate the fields on memberpage.asp
      pnlMain.Visible = true
      litJS.visible = true
    End Sub
    

    Private Sub resizeImage(ByVal location As String)
             ' Get the source bitmap.
             Dim bm_source As Bitmap = system.drawing.image.fromfile(location)
        
            If bm_source.Width > 450 Then
                Dim PercentageScaleWidth As Decimal = 450 / bm_source.Width
            
                ' Make a bitmap for the result.
                Dim bm_dest As New Bitmap( _
                    CInt(bm_source.Width * PercentageScaleWidth), _
                    CInt(bm_source.Height * PercentageScaleWidth))

                ' Make a Graphics object for the result Bitmap.
                Dim gr_dest As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bm_dest)

                ' Copy the source image into the destination bitmap.
                gr_dest.DrawImage(bm_source, 0, 0, _
                    bm_dest.Width + 1, _
                    bm_dest.Height + 1)

                ' Save the result.
                bm_source.Dispose()
                bm_source = Nothing

                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
            
                bm_dest.Save(location)
                bm_dest.Dispose()
                bm_dest = Nothing
    
                gr_dest.Dispose()
                gr_dest = Nothing
            else
            
                bm_source.Dispose()
                bm_source = Nothing
            
            End If
              

    End Sub
```

Comment: When you say that the file doesn't compress as much, what format are we talking about.  It looks like your script supports Bitmaps and JPGS and that is like WAV vs MP3, as in JPG compresses very well and handles decent interpolation .   If you can turn a BMP into a JPG for example, its usually much smaller.

Comment: it sounds like you're resampling the image file as you save it.  Basically, the uploaded jpg has been optimized for its size, with a good match between pixel and physical dimensions. Your resize methodology changes the physical size, but doesn't address the pixel dimensions. Which means it uses the default which would upsample the image, adding data to it, thus a larger file size.

Comment: @StephenWrighton Interesting comment regarding the physical size that doesn't address the pixel dimensions.  I can always change the dimensions with CSS on the webpage.  So perhaps I don't need the 450 width code; I believe that is what you are saying?  I am not good at ASP.net, so would I just take out those 2 lines of code that deal with that?  Or if you could, what would you recommend that I try to see if that theory works?

Answer (score 0):

I have had some jpg's resized from 375 kb to 660 kb.  Seems odd that it would be larger which is why I was hoping that altering the code would cure that.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: There is a form of progressive dithering that can be done to reduce the quality of the image but also reduce the file size.  Increasing interpolation  would also reduce the file size.  Granted I have no i idea how to do that with the above script but a desktop photo editor can pull both off with ease.